# How to programmatically navigate using react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

When using react-router I can use the Link element to create links that are natively handled by react router.

I see internally it calls this.context.transitionTo(...).

I want to do a navigation, but not from a link, from a dropdown selection for example. How can I do this in code? What is this.context?

I saw the Navigation mixin, but can I do this without mixin's?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to install the history package `npm install history` and then pass an instance of it to your router:

```js
import { Router } from "react-router";
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";

const history = createBrowserHistory()

<Router history={history}>
  <App/>
</Router>
```

Then you can programmatically navigate anywhere in your app by using `withRouter` to get your history instance and doing something like this `history.push("/my-path")`.

You can also set up a file that creates/exports your history instance that you can just import.

Technically you don't need the history package as react-router will pass its own, but if you're doing this you'll prefer the flexibility that your own history instance will provide.

Comment: You can also create a history object in a separate module kinda 'history.util.js' and import it from there so as to make it accessible outside components.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Redirect component from router?

This is the example:

```
<Redirect to="/login" exact component={Login} />
```